# php script to execute commands on Cisco router

Tags: php, cisco

I need to write a script to connect to a Cisco router and execute commands. The linux server and the Cisco router use ssh keys so no username/password are required. I have worked out how to make the connection, but I don't know how to issue the commands and read the responses.

Note: It has to be in php to integrate with some other stuff we have going on.

Here is what I have so far :-

```
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect("n.n.n.n", 22, array("hostkey"=>"ssh-rsa"));

if(!$connection)
{
  die("Could not connect to the Router \n\r");
  exit();
}

if (ssh2_auth_none ($connection, "username"))
{
  echo("Public Key Authentication Successful\n\r");
}
else
{
  die("Public Key Authentication Failed");
  exit();
}


// New commands based on help received
try
{
  $command = "dir";
  $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);

  // added to test if the ssh2_exec command returns false - which it does, issue is with the command ???
  if(!$stream)
  {
    echo("Command returned False\n\r");
    exit();
  }

  $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
  stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
  stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
  $errorStreamContent = stream_get_contents($errorStream);
  $streamContent = stream_get_contents($stream);
  echo("ErrorStream : " . $errorStreamContent . "\n" . "Stream : " . 
  $streamContent . "\n\r");
}

catch(exception $e)
{
  echo("Error : " . $e);
  exit();
}

?>
```

Output is now as follows :-

```
Public Key Authentication Successful
Command returned False
```

Can anyone give me the correct way to issue commands and read any result ? Thanks.

Comment: Try shell_exec http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Hi @paskl, that just issued the command to the linux O/S, not the router.

Comment: Oopsie, you are right. How about ```ssh2_exec``` ? ;)

Comment: @paskl - I issued the following command  `$result = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);` I didn't get an error this time, but $result is empty. The $command is a `dir` so I would expect to see a list of files (which is what I see if I issue dir on the router manually).

Comment: Check the docs in order to find out how to read the stream. The comments on the functions docs page on php.net are really helpful. :) (No point in repeating them here)

Comment: OK I'll take a look

Comment: Hi @paskl - OK I found some stuff on reading the stream, I have amended my question with some new code to show where I am at, but I still have no output from the `dir` command (or any other command I try).

Comment: It looks like the `ssh2_exec($connection, $command)` command is returning false, not sure what I'm missing there.

Comment: Hi @ paskl. I managed to fix this by using `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` to pass the ssh keys to the router and authenticate. After that it works fine. If you can create an answer with your contribution I will accept that as you put me on the right path. Many thanks.

Comment: Good job! Answer yourself, it yields more points I believe. I dont care much about points. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using ssh2_auth_pubkey_file to pass the ssh keys to the router and authenticate. After that it works fine.